# How to show dynamic character coming from server to textView in android

Tags: android

Please any one tell me that how can I show character like ï¿½cija in android textview.
i.e some spanish word I have to show in textview

Answer (score 0):

Use Unicode Format for this, It will work for sure. I Use Chinese character and it worked pretty well for me.

Do something like this for an example

```
 TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
 t.setText(Character.toString('\u4E01'));
```

What so ever character you want to print put its unicode value in the string.
It will for sure show you the Chinese character in view. if you are not able to see your character even after putting its unicode. then check for the authentication of unicode character is it right unicode or not.

Comment: did you tested the chinese character?

Comment: check this unicode character of your on some other code say make a c or c++ program separately to print this. and tell the result of that

Comment: if this character is coming from server this could create a a problem. Do ensure first that server is sending this character after encoding it in UTF-8 Format and then decode it then using the same UTF-8 format. Do ensure the coding format from both the side. as it could be different